# Backbone JS populating model/collection correctly

Tags: javascript, php, templates, backbone.js

I have a collection which contains one model.  In my template I should be able to do:

```
<% _.each(collection, function(model) { %> 
  <p>logged in <%= model.username %>!</p>
<% }); %>
```

But I've found I need to do:

```
<% _.each(models, function(model) { %> 
<p>logged in <%= model.attributes.username %>!</p>
<% }); %>
```

I'm not sure exactly what the problem is but the model isn't being populated properly.  Anyone know why this is happening and how I can set the values within the model so I can loop over a collection of models and access the values simply with model.username ?

Thank you in advance.

Here's my model and collection:

```
var AccountModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: 
{
    username: "bob"
}
});

var AccountCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend(
{
    model: AccountModel,
    url: "/php/account-details.php",

    parse: function(data, xhr)
    {
   return data
    },

    initialize: function()
    {

    }
});
```

Here's my fetch function:

```
fetchAccountCollection: function(){

   var $this = this;

$this.homepageAccountCollection = new AccountCollection();

$this.homepageAccountCollection.fetch(
{
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,

    success: function(collection)
    {
      Backbone.trigger('accountcollection:loaded', collection);
    },

    error: function()
    {
      console.log("fetchAccountCollection: error");
    }
});
```

},

When the success function is called the trigger invokes the render function within the controller:

```
renderAccount: function(collection)
{
  var $this = this;

  $this.loginPageView = new LoginView(
  { 
    el: '#login-form',
    template: 'loggedin-template',
    collection: collection
  });

$this.loginPageView.render();
},
```

When $this.loginPageView.render(); is called the following code is executed:

```
render: function() 
{
var collection = this.options.collection;
    var tpl = _.template($(this.options.template).html(), collection);
    this.$el.html(tpl);

    return this;
},
```

The value of the username is being returned from a PHP script like so:

```
         $array=array('username' => $user['username']);
         echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your passing a `Backbone.Collection` to your template, so when you end up calling the following in your template:

```
_.each(models,function(model) { ... });
```

You are iterating through `collection.models` array which is an array of `Backbone.Model`'s. Since a `Backbone.Model` stores model values within the `attributes` property, you have to access via `model.attributes.username`, you could also use `model.get('username')`, which would work as well.

As you stated, you would like to access via `model.username`, and you can do that by calling `collection.toJSON()` before passing it to the template, you have to put it in an object such as, `{collection:collection.toJSON()};`. Check out the [documentation for toJSON](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON). The method exists for both `Backbone.Collection` and a `Backbone.Model`.

The code would be the following:

```
render: function()  {
  var collection = this.options.collection;
  var tpl = _.template($(this.options.template).html(), {collection:collection.toJSON());
  this.$el.html(tpl);
  return this;
}
```

Then you could use your template like:

```
 <% _.each(collection, function(model) { %> 
   <p>logged in <%= model.username %>!</p>
 <% }); %>
```

Here is a minimal [JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/UGUCegix/1/edit).

As a side note: It looks like your using a version of backbone < 1.1.0. Just be aware `this.options` goes away in the newer versions. When you upgrade be sure to have a look at the [Change Log](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  That's what I was looking for.  Thanks also for the advice on the backbone version.

Answer (score 1):

Underscore's `each` method (and many others) are mixed directly into the collection. Use `collection.each(function () { ... })` instead of `_.each(collection ...)`.